# Colors for loop-generated scatter plot

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a 3D data cube which I scatter plot using a loop. I want the scatter points to be the cube index, and the color of the scatter points to be the value. Below is code that yields all one color. How do I make the colors based on the value?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
%matplotlib 

# I have a 3D array of numbers of unknown shape containing unknown 
# integer values within an unknown range.
# Here, I made this toy 3D array with shape 9,10,11 containing random 
# integer values 0-10.

xyz = np.random.rand(9,10,111)*100//10

# Determine the shape of the the array

x_size = np.shape(xyz)[0]
y_size = np.shape(xyz)[1]
z_size = np.shape(xyz)[2]

# Scatter plot the array

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
for xi in range(x_size):
    for yi in range(y_size):
        for zi in range(z_size):
            ax.scatter(xi, yi, zi, c=xyz[xi, yi, zi])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# I have a 3D array of numbers of unknown shape containing unknown
# integer values within an unknown range.
# Here, I made this toy 3D array with shape 9,10,11 containing random
# integer values 0-10.

xyz = np.random.rand(9,10,111)*100//10

# Determine the shape of the the array

x_size = np.shape(xyz)[0]
y_size = np.shape(xyz)[1]
z_size = np.shape(xyz)[2]

# Scatter plot the array

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
xi, yi, zi = np.meshgrid(range(x_size), range(y_size), range(z_size))
ax.scatter(xi, yi, zi, c=xyz)
plt.show()
```